# Remove the installed BaseImage-14393 is not possible

Tags: desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I can't remove the directory C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Images\BaseImage-14393

Every method including admin prompt is not able to remove the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the ownership of the directory to yourself and then give yourself Full control to the directory. After this, you can then delete the folder using the combination Shift + Del.

See the answer from Franklin Chen in this forum thread for detailed steps if needed.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dce87a60-629a-4c11-bb7e-e0252311137f/uwpdesktop-app-converter-remove-old-baseimage-14316?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command which deletes all the expanded base images installed on your host machine.
Process may take a while.

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe -Cleanup ExpandedImage
```